# заполнение массива четные ячейки

Tags: массивы, циклы

дан одномерный массив из 12 ячеек. заполните его четные ячейки начиная с 0 в цикле.
значение нулевой ячейки 625, каждая последующая четная ячейка должна быть больше предыдущей на 625

Правильно я понял что должно получиться
{625, 0, 1250, 0, 1875, 0, 2500, 0, 3125, 0, 3750, 0}

как это сделать

Comment: По сути, правильно. Но, составители таких заданий косноязычны или не понимают разницы, между _чётной ячейкой_ и _чётным индексом ячейки_. Мол, понимай, как хочешь.

Comment: скорее всего имелся индекс

Comment: *как это сделать* Наиболее вероятно, что надо написать программу, выполняющую указанную операцию.

Comment: Указывайте в метках язык программирования

Answer (score 1):

правильно

сделать можно так:

0. инициализируете переменную и устанавливаете ее значение в 625
1. пройти в цикле от 0 до 11 ячейки включительно
2. если номер ячейки чётный, то

   - пишете туда значение переменной, в которой накапливаете значения
   - увеличиваете значение переменной на 625
3. если номер ячейки нечётный, то пишите 0

или можете

0. инициализируете переменную и устанавливаете ее значение в 625
1. заполнить весь массив нулями
2. пройти в цикле от 0 до 11 ячейки включительно с шагом 2

   - пишете туда значение переменной, в которой накапливаете значения
   - увеличиваете значение переменной на 625

или вам на каком-то конкретном языке программирования алгоритм нужен? :)

Comment: подавляющее число языков программирование, наверео, умеют инкрементировать счетчик цикла на указаный шаг. нет смысла вообще заходить в нечетные ячейки и проверять при этом четность. а просто ходить с 0 по i+=2

Comment: @teran, но ведь в нечётных должны быть 0, как вы их заполните иначе? или вначале вызывать функцию или по ходу цикла

Comment: первоначально была мысль
int16 arr[12];
for (int i=0; i<12; i+2)
    arr[i] = 625 + 625*i;
но все портит ячейка с индексом 0

Comment: @Zhihar либо целочисленный массив изначально средствами самого языка будет заполнен нулями при инициализации, либо какой-нибудь метод `zeromemory`, заполняющий нулями. сам по себе явный цикл заполнения особо не нужен.

Comment: и чем же она портит? 
можно сделать так было бы: `625 * (i + 1)` вот только раз идете через 2 клетки, то и делайте так: `625 * (i / 2 + 1)`

Comment: @Zhihar портит там видимо то, что `i+2` а не ` i+=2`

Comment: Да, действительно, Вы правы, премного благодарен

Comment: Всем спасибо, вопрос решен,

Answer (score 1):

Самый простейший и очевидный вариант:

```js
// Создаём массив из 12-и ячеек
const arr = new Array(12);
// Значение для 1-ой ячейки, имеющей индекс 0
arr[0] = 625;
/* Перебор ячеек массива в цикле */
for (let i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
  // Заносим в ячейку с индексом i, если она имеет нечётный индекс - 0, 
  // иначе заносим значение, основываясь на содержании предыдущей 
  // чётной ячейки, увеличивая его на 625
  arr[i] = (i % 2) ? 0 : arr[i - 2] + 625;
}
// Выводим получившийся массив в консоль
console.log(arr);
```

Без предварительного заполнения первой ячейки:

```js
// Создаём массив из 12-и ячеек
const arr = new Array(12);
/* Перебор ячеек массива в цикле */
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  // Заносим в ячейку с индексом i, если она имеет нечётный индекс - 0
  arr[i] = (i % 2) ? 0 : i / 2 * 625 + 625;
}
// Выводим получившийся массив в консоль
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: ясно. но это если 0 индекс заполнен вне цикла, а как быть если заполнение начинается с пустого массива?

Comment: @Дима: дополнил.

Comment: в первом примере при нечётном кол-во элементом последний чётный вроде как заполнен не будет ;-)

Comment: @Zhihar: а проверить? ;-)